# Why is this tiny library function returning undefined?

Tags: javascript

I want to build a tiny JavaScript library that can be used like this:

```
library('input').method()
```

```js
(async () => {
  // const nlp = function (text = '', lexicon) {
  const library = function (text) {
    const options = {}

    options.addQuotes = function (text) {
      return `"${text}"`
    }

    return options
  }

  const result= library('test').addQuotes()
  console.log(result)
})()
```

`library.addQuotes` is suppose to surround `text` around double quotes.

So I thought `result` would be:

```
"test"
```

Instead I got:

```
"undefined"
```

Why is this, and how to fix it?

Comment: Because of the additional `text` parameter which expects an argument that you don’t pass to `addQuotes`, overshadowing the outer `text`. A linter would’ve told you that the outer `text` is never used.

Comment: Remove the parameter from the `addQuotes` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By having an extra parameter you are creating an inner variable `text` (scoped inside the addQuotes function). You do not pass any value and JS has not problem with that, only it will be `undefined`. When JS looks for `text` variable, it finds this `undefined` value and returns that.

Remove that extra argument name and you are good.

```js
(async () => {
  // const nlp = function (text = '', lexicon) {
  const library = function (text) {
    const options = {}

    options.addQuotes = function () {
      return `"${text}"`
    }

    return options
  }

  const result= library('test').addQuotes()
  console.log(result)
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `text` parameter in the `addQuotes` function is overshadowing the `text` variable in the outer scope.

Remove the parameter from the `addQuotes` function:

```js
(async () => {
  // const nlp = function (text = '', lexicon) {
  const library = function (text) {
    const options = {}

    options.addQuotes = function () {
      return `"${text}"`
    }

    return options
  }

  const result= library('test').addQuotes()
  console.log(result)
})()
```